# How to do a vertical drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

i try to realize how to do a vertical drop-down menu like on this site: http://haririsportsandmedicals.de/

It should "drop-down" when the onClick event happens and not at mousover.

Has anyone a code sample for doing something like this?

Would be very great, thanks.

Comment: add class on onclick event on that a tag. if you use onclick event, it won't work href attribute.you could write href value on onclick event

Comment: your code is working for onhover, how is it difficult for you to change it to onclick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
}

li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
}

li ul{
    display: none;
}

li li a{
    margin-left: 10px;    
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n6pvw/1/)

Comment: how to keep the drop-down menu open, after clicking on a link in the sub-menu?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this. I think its pretty close to what you are seeking.

Demo: http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/verticalnav/index.html

Tutorial/Guide: http://designshack.net/articles/css/verticalaccordionav/